# Enabling URL-based imports on codesandbox.io

Tags: javascript, codesandbox

I currently get the following error, when attempting to use a URL-based import on codesandbox.io:

> ESModules url imports are only supported in the experimental ESModule
> preset.

In which configuration file does this preset reside?

Comment: Can you provide a package.json and relevant config files? Thanks.

Comment: Related: [CSB GH 1](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/discussions/6449) and [CSB GH 2](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/discussions/6758)